# WebDeleting Event for New Sites created  ? ? 

Tags: 2007, event-handlers, feature-activation, feature

I am using the WebDeleting event which is based on features. Just activate the feature, and whenever a web is getting deleted, the event handler throws a message saying "Web can't be deleted".

Everything works fine for all the existing sites. But suppose a client adds 5-10 sites? How should I go about attaching the event handlers to new sites which are created?

I thought of going for Job Schedulers which work on attaching every minute or second.. 
Or is there another approach? Please provide links if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use Feature Stapling to bind your feature to new sites.